# GCP API Gateway with multiple gRPC backend services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have two (backend) gRPC cloud run services and I would like to expose both of them in a singe API Gateway. I have successfully exposed one of the two services through a gateway by following the tutorial at https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-run-grpc. However, I cannot find an example with multiple backend services. I have tried modifying the `api_config.yaml` file from the tutorial as follows:

```yaml
apis:
  - name: FirstService
  - name: SecondService
backend:                                  
  rules:
    - selector: 'FirstService.*'
      address: 'grpcs://first-cloud-run-service-url'
    - selector: 'SecondService.*'
      address: 'grpcs://second-cloud-run-service-url'
```

The two services are described by two separate `.proto` files (which, ideally, I don't want to modify). I generate two separate descriptor `.pb` files from them and pass them both to `--grpc-files` argument of `gcloud api-gateway api-configs create`. (`--grpc-files=first_descriptor.pb,second_descriptor.pb,api_config.yaml`)

With this I get the following errors:

```
message: "Cannot resolve api \'FirstService\'."
message: "backend rule has selector(s) \'FirstService.*\' that do not match and are not shadowed by other rules."
```

It seems that the second `.pb` file somehow replaces the first. (When I comment out all lines related to the first service in `api_config.yaml` it works.)

Comment: Have you tried generating a single descriptor file for all your protos? I use Cloud Endpoints and encountered a similar problem trying to provide multiple descriptor files.

Comment: Yes, compiling multiple .proto files into a single .pb file and then submitting the .pb file when creating the config works as long as the .proto files are compatible. However, in my case I have name clashes between the two .proto files and I'm wondering if there's a way to expose both APIs through the same gateway without modifying the .proto files. (If not I would also have to change the backend service which uses them.)